# Publishing with .dbproj turns off transparent data encryption

Tags: sql, encryption, azure-sql-database, tde, dbproj

I noticed in the Azure Dashboard that something was turning off Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on my database. I had turned it on through the Azure Portal. Realized that something in my `dbproj` publish process included:

`SET ENCRYPTION OFF`

There is no obvious option that would do such a thing in the publish screen.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of trial and error, I found that deselecting the checkbox `Deploy database properties` stopped the publish script from including the junk about turning off encryption. Then it was a matter of finding which db property was causing this.

[image]

I saw my `dbproj` target platform was set to `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` not `Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12`. V12 is what has TDE, the old db does not.

Once you go to the properties on your dbproj (right click proj > properties), go to project setttings, change to V12, then click on `Database Settings`. Go to `Miscellaneous` tab and check `Encryption enabled`. Voila, you're done. Make sure you have `Deploy database properties` re-enabled in your publish settings.

[image]

[image]